# Pandas converting column to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Python pandas dataframe:

```
id| country  | 2016 | 2017 | 2018
--+----------+------+------+------
0 | saudi    | A    | null | B
1 | china    | C    | A    | B
2 | pakistan | null | null | C
```

I want:

```
id| country  | year | value
--+----------+------+------
0 | saudi    | 2016 | A
1 | saudi    | 2018 | B
2 | china    | 2016 | C
3 | china    | 2017 | A
4 | china    | 2018 | B
5 | pakistan | 2018 | C
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [df.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html)

```
df.melt(['id','country'], df.columns[2:]).dropna()

    id  country variable  value
0   0   saudi     2016     A
6   0   saudi     2018     B
1   1   china     2016     C
4   1   china     2017     A
7   1   china     2018     B
8   2   pakistan  2018     C
```

Then just add `.sort_values('id')` if you want

Or you can use `stack`

```
df.set_index(['id','country']).stack().to_frame()
```

and then `.reset_index()` if you want

It looks like using `stack` will be a little more efficient:

```
melt: 11.3 ms ± 798 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1000 loops each)

stack: 9.18 ms ± 594 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you may also use [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) `df2=df.unstack()` and then `df2.reset_index()`